# Sails: How to insert data for one to one association in sails v1.0?

Tags: sails.js

Sails stops working after upgrading to v1.0. I am facing issue with following one to one association.

#### Modal

User

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'number',
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      description: 'Full representation of the user\'s name',
      maxLength: 120,
      example: 'Lisa Microwave van der Jenny'
    },
    hospitals: {
      collection: 'hospital',
      via: 'users'
    },
    profile: {
      collection: 'profile',
      via: 'userId'
    }
  }
};
```

Profile

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'number',
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    type: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
    },
    userId: {
      model: 'user'
    }
  },
};
```

Earlier I was able to store User with Profile by passing profile within user data, like following.

```
const userParams = {
  "name": "farhan1",
  "hospitals": [1],
  "profile": {
    "type": "Cool"
  }
};
User.create(userParams, (err, created) => {
  console.log(err, created, 'COOL');
  if(err) {return res.serverError(err);}
  return res.ok(created);
});
```

But with sails v1 it doesn't allow me to do it, it throws following error

```
UsageError: Invalid new record.
Details:
  Could not use specified `profile`.  If specified, expected profile` 
to be an array of ids (representing the records to associate).  But 
instead, got: { type: 'Cool' }
```

Let me know if I missed something or doing something wrong?

Thanks